# What does the @guaranteed attribute in Swift do?

Tags: swift

What does the @guaranteed attribute do in swift? I've seen it used in this [blog post](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/blog/2016/06/02/threads-and-mutexes.html) but couldn't understand it.

Here is an excerpt from the post, I am referring to.

> We can force the compiler to avoid these retains and releases by
>   making the function an extension on PThreadMutex, rather than a free
>   function:
>
> ```
> extension PThreadMutex {
>    private func sync<R>(execute: () throws -> R) rethrows -> R {
>       pthread_mutex_lock(&m)
>       defer { pthread_mutex_unlock(&m) }
>       return try execute()
>    }
> }
> ```
>
> This forces Swift to treat the `self` parameter as `@guaranteed`,
>   eliminating retain/release overhead and we’re finally down to the
>   baseline 0.264 seconds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@guaranteed` is not an attribute that's available to use in Swift itself, it's actually a [SIL](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/SIL.rst) (Swift Intermediate Language) attribute – which defines a function parameter memory management convention.

[The three possible conventions](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/CallingConvention.rst#known-conventions) for parameter passing are:

- **unowned** – Neither the caller or callee assert ownership of the passed value, but it is guaranteed to be valid at the time of the call (unless the callee does something to invalidate this).
- **owned** – The callee has ownership of the value. The caller will retain the value before passing it, and then it's the responsibility of the callee to release it once done with it.
- **guaranteed** – The caller asserts ownership of the value, allowing the callee to have the guarantee that it will be valid at the time of call.

In the post you mention, `sync(mutex:execute:)` is originally defined as a global function, which (AFAIK) by default will use the *owned* convention for its parameters. Therefore the value passed to the `mutex` parameter will be retained by the caller before being passed to the function, which it will then release once finished with it.

However, this retain/release overhead for the owned convention is unecessary if the value passed to the function has a lifetime that extends beyond the function call, which is most likely the case with a mutex. As the post observes, even after the inlining the call, the compiler doesn't eliminate this retain/release overhead.

Therefore, as stated, the solution is to treat the `mutex:` parameter as *guaranteed*, which will allow the compiler to eliminate the overhead, as if the mutex is already retained by the caller, then there's no need for any further retains in order to guarantee its existence for the duration of the `sync` call.

The way to do this, as the post says, is to make a `sync` an instance method of `PThreadMutex`. This is because, as [Joe Groff says in this mailing list discussion](https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-dev/Week-of-Mon-20160118/000861.html), as of Swift 2, instance methods will treat the `self` parameter as guaranteed.

Comment: Nice answer. (Here I thought it meant you'd be 100% satisfied with that value or you could get your money back. ;)